# Watch-video.net pop-ups using Chrome

Tags: popup-ads

I've start to get pop-ups from watch-video.net when using Chrome. The pop-ups are about adult material, and nothing that I'm interesting in.

I've search this site (and the web), for help, but nothing how to fix this on Ubuntu, for other OS there is help to get.

I have tried to look into Chrome setting, but cantfind anything strange, I also added watch-video.net in the block list, but that did not helped.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, and I hope that you can help me!

//Björn

Comment: "for other OS there is help to get." list some. The answer for Chrome will be the same on all operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove in from the URL `chrome://settings/content/notifications`

It will have " watch-video.net" or "blastnotificationsx.com" in the list of notifications. Delete them. Also have a look through cookies for similar names.

And lastly make sure to track down the Chrome Extension that causes this (Chrome menu-icon, Extensions).

Comment: Hi,
in chrome://settings/content/notifications ther where no blastnotificationsx.com, but there where watch-video.net in the allow list, very strang, because i've checked that are not long ago. watch-video.net is in the block list.

In Chrome Extension Chrome menu-icoon, Extensions I cant find anything suspiciouse.
//Björn

Comment: @Björn Along with removing watch-video.net from your notifications allow list, you'll have to look in your cookies to find one from the same/similar.

Comment: @Björn check added that one too I got the other one from an online search ;-)